# How to change class with jquery based on index?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a gallery on Shopify that has webp support (long story).

I'm 99% there, the images display correctly. I just need to change some classes based on the thumbnail that is clicked.

There is a liquid loop that creates all the "main" images, all bar the first have a class "main-image-hidden" which hides it.

Another liquid loop creates the thumbnails, the first has a class "thumb-active" which sets the opacity to 0.5 to show that it's active.

I had a clear idea in my head on how to do it. An example being, if you click a thumbnail with data-slide-index="3", the following happens:
+ The main image with index 3 removes class "main-image-hidden"
+ The main images (that was previously active) gets the class "main-image-hidden"
+ The thumbnail that with index 3 gets class "thumb-active"
+ The thumbnail (that was previously active) loses the class "thumb-active"
(The index needs to be a variable for obvious reasons!)

Is there anyone kind enough to point me in the right direction for this?

Thanks in advance.

'''

```
    <div class="popup-gallery center" style="max-height:500px; padding-bottom: 10%;">
      {%- for image in product.images -%}
      {% assign webp_url = image.src | img_url: '1x1' | replace: 'products', 'files' | split: 'x' %}

    <a href="{{ webp_url[0] }}x1000.webp" alt="{{ image.alt }}"  class="main-image {% if forloop.first == false %}main-image-hidden{% endif %}" data-slide-index="{{ forloop.index0 }}">

        <picture>
          <source type="image/webp" class="lazy"
                  data-src="{{ webp_url[0] }}x500.webp 1x"
                  data-srcset="{{ webp_url[0] }}x1000.webp 2x,
                               {{ webp_url[0] }}x500.webp 1x">
          <img alt="{{ image.alt }}" class="lazy" 
               data-src="{{ webp_url[0] }}x500.png 1x" 
               data-srcset="{{ webp_url[0] }}x1000.png 2x,
                            {{ webp_url[0] }}x500.png 1x">
        </picture>
        <noscript>
          <img alt="{{ image.alt }}" src="{{ webp_url[0] }}x50.png">
        </noscript>
      </a>
      {%- endfor -%}
    </div>


    {%- if product.images.size > 1 -%}

    <div class="center">
      {%- for image in product.images -%}
      {% assign webp_url = image.src | img_url: '1x1' | replace: 'products', 'files' | split: 'x' %}

      <div style="padding: 0 1%; display:inline-block;" class="thumb {% if forloop.first %}thumb-active{% endif %}" data-slide-index="{{ forloop.index0 }}">

        <picture>
          <source type="image/webp" class="lazy"
                  data-src="{{ webp_url[0] }}x50.webp 1x"
                  data-srcset="{{ webp_url[0] }}x100.webp 2x,
                               {{ webp_url[0] }}x50.webp 1x">
          <img alt="{{ image.alt }}" class="lazy" style="max-height:50px"
               data-src="{{ webp_url[0] }}}x50.png 1x" 
               data-srcset="{{ webp_url[0] }}x100.png 2x,
                            {{ webp_url[0] }}x50.png 1x">
        </picture>
        <noscript>
          <img alt="{{ image.alt }}" src="{{ webp_url[0] }}x50.png">
        </noscript>
      </div>
      {%- endfor -%}
    </div>

    {%- endif -%}


  </div>
```

'''

I've tried various time but can take into account the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you want to do. You can use a CSS attribute selector with jQuery to find an element with the value of `data-slide-index`. Does this event do it for you?

```
$('.thumb').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).attr('data-slide-index');

    $('.main-image').addClass('main-image-hidden');
    $('.main-image[data-slide-index=' + index + ']').removeClass('main-image-hidden');

    $('.thumb-active').removeClass('thumb-active');
    $(this).addClass('thumb-active');
});
```

Comment: It does indeed - you legend! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//This method first get the index after using javascript add style in the this index

<script>
    var serach_main_wrpa = document.getElementsByClassName('serach_main_wrpa');
    function showContent(event) {
       
       
        $(".diamondType").each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                var numItems = $(this).index();
                $(this).removeClass("active");
                serach_main_wrpa[numItems].style.display = "none";
                console.log(numItems);
            }
            $(event).addClass("active");
        });
    }

</script>
```